# delegate std::less or std::greater in condition

Tags: c++

I have already implemented a test case where I can have key as custom class as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class CoordinateValue
{
public:

    short int x_;
    short int y_;

    CoordinateValue(short int x = 0, short int y = 0)
    : x_(x),y_(y)
    {

    }

    bool operator<=(const CoordinateValue &right) const
    {
      return ((this->x_ <= right.x_) && (this->y_ <= right.y_));
    }

    bool operator<(const CoordinateValue &right) const
    {
      return ((this->x_ < right.x_) && (this->y_ < right.y_));
    }

    bool operator>=(const CoordinateValue &right) const
    {
      return ((this->x_ >= right.x_) && (this->y_ >= right.y_));
    }

    bool operator>(const CoordinateValue &right) const
    {
      return ((this->x_ > right.x_) && (this->y_ > right.y_));
    }


    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const CoordinateValue &val)
    {
      out << "[ " << val.x_ << "," << val.y_ << " ]" << std::endl;

      return out;
    }
} ;

int main()
{

    std::multimap<CoordinateValue,int,std::less_equal<CoordinateValue>> intersectionIn;


    intersectionIn.insert(std::pair<CoordinateValue,int>(CoordinateValue(100,200),12));
    intersectionIn.insert(std::pair<CoordinateValue,int>(CoordinateValue(1000,7),135));
    intersectionIn.insert(std::pair<CoordinateValue,int>(CoordinateValue(0,2),112));
    intersectionIn.insert(std::pair<CoordinateValue,int>(CoordinateValue(-10,-200),12));
    intersectionIn.insert(std::pair<CoordinateValue,int>(CoordinateValue(-100,-200),12));
    intersectionIn.insert(std::pair<CoordinateValue,int>(CoordinateValue(1000,2000),12));

    std::multimap<CoordinateValue,int,std::greater<CoordinateValue>>::const_iterator iter = intersectionIn.begin();

    while(iter != intersectionIn.end())
    {
        std::cout << iter->first;
        ++iter;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Now I want call std::greater / std::less / std::less_equal based on some condition. How do I delegate ? For example for one condition I declare the container with std::less and for other condition I declare the container with std::greater.

Some hint or reference would be great to have.

Thanks

Comment: On compile time conditions ? or runtime one ?

Comment: I want to have it on runtime

Comment: You are using a `const_iterator` from a `std::map` with `std::greater` to iterate over one with `std::less`, is it intended?

Comment: If you just want to change between greater and less you cuold use the reverse iterator. Changing template paramters (the compare) is not possible on runtime.

Comment: I am sorry for the last comment. I want to have it on compile-time. And the iterator is only test if the comparator - less<>/greater<> and it was a mistake . It should have been std::less_equal instead.

Comment: Can you use `c++11`? If so, have a look at [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional). And what are your conditions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a runtime version (from your comment), you can use the type `std::function<bool(int, int)>` as your `Compare` type in `multimap` and then store either `std::less` or `std::greater` when creating the map:

```
std::function<bool(int, int)> cmp;
if (...) {
    cmp = std::less<int>();
}
else {
    cmp = std::greater<int>();
}
std::multimap<int, int, decltype(cmp)> map(cmp);
```

Code on ideone: http://ideone.com/cP0OEm

---

Old compile time version below:

If you can use `c++11`, you could use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
template <typename T>
using cmp = typename std::conditional<cond, std::greater<T>, std::less<T>>::type;
```

Where `cond` is your condition, and you can chain `std::conditional` for multiple conditions.

And then:

```
std::multimap<int, int, cmp<int>> map;
```

Since you did not say what your conditions were, I cannot add more information.

After your comment, this could look like this:

```
template <int value, typename T>
using cmp = typename std::conditional<(value > 0), std::less<T>, std::greater<T>>::type;

std::multimap<int, int, cmp<MY_VALUE, int>> map;
```

Where `MY_VALUE` is a compile time constant.

Comment: If  a particular value is greater than 0, the contents of the container are arranged in ascending order , else it is arranged in descending order while inserting into the container.

Comment: @user1355185 And this particular value is known at compile time?

Comment: I strongly guess that it is runtime. Let me break it down more. I have end points of  a line segment. I find out the direction of the line segment by deducting the end point from the start point. If the direction is Greater than Zero , I store the coordinate values in ascending order else in the descending order.

Comment: @user1355185 I doubt this is compile time, or you have a very strange program... I have updated my answer to provide a runtime version.

Comment: Why can't the variable `cmp` in the first code block not be assigned using a ternary? I get a compile-time error: `Incompatible operand types` when I try to do so. But if I set both conditions of the ternary to `std::greater`, then it works?

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees Because there are specific rules for what you can have in ternary, in particular `std::less` and `std::greater` are completely independent classes, so you cannot convert one to the other or vice-versa. They can both be converted to `std::function<>` but that's not sufficient for a ternary, See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637152/strange-implicit-conversions-with-the-ternary-operator/41637450#41637450 for more details.