# Compiling Kevlin Henney's Fizzbuzz with the use of lambdas in C++17 using Visual Studio 2017's compiler

Tags: c++, lambda, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, c++17

I was following [Kevlin Henney's Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nItSZp6R8tg) on Lambdas in programming. At about 20:30 - 20:40 in his video he gives this code snippet:

```
string fizzbuzz(int n)
{
    auto fizz = [=](function<string(string)> f)
    {
        return n % 3 == 0 ? [=](auto) {return "Fizz" + f("");} : f;
    };
    auto buzz = [=](function<string(string)> f)
    {
        return n % 5 == 0 ? [=](auto) {return "Buzz" + f("");} : f;
    };
    auto id = [](auto s) { return s; };
    return fizz(buzz(id))(to_string(n));
}
```

Here is my actual code within my IDE:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string fizzbuzz(int n) {
    auto fizz = [=](std::function<std::string(std::string)> f) {
        return n % 3 == 0 ? [=](auto) { return "Fizz" + f(""); } : f;
    };
    auto buzz = [=](std::function<std::string(std::string)> f) {
        return n % 5 == 0 ? [=](auto) { return "Buzz" + f(""); } : f;
    };
    auto id = [](auto s) { return s; };
    return fizz(buzz(id))(std::to_string(n));
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        std::cout << fizzbuzz(i) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to compile this Visual Studio is generating these compiler errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Data Structure Samples, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\...\main.cpp(62): error C2445: result type of conditional expression is ambiguous: types 'fizzbuzz::<lambda_9027e592dd51e6f4c5342b61ff8c23f0>::()::<lambda_2463463a8046fa170a40e78d59e9f461>' and 'std::function<std::string (std::string)>' can be converted to multiple common types
1>c:\...\main.cpp(62): note: could be 'fizzbuzz::<lambda_9027e592dd51e6f4c5342b61ff8c23f0>::()::<lambda_2463463a8046fa170a40e78d59e9f461>'
1>c:\...\main.cpp(62): note: or       'std::function<std::string (std::string)>'
1>c:\...\main.cpp(65): error C2445: result type of conditional expression is ambiguous: types 'fizzbuzz::<lambda_c18a2fee5ba13240be9b86f815911a7c>::()::<lambda_2774da13f447e3dfb583778d4ea6d5bd>' and 'std::function<std::string (std::string)>' can be converted to multiple common types
1>c:\...\main.cpp(65): note: could be 'fizzbuzz::<lambda_c18a2fee5ba13240be9b86f815911a7c>::()::<lambda_2774da13f447e3dfb583778d4ea6d5bd>'
1>c:\...\main.cpp(65): note: or       'std::function<std::string (std::string)>'
1>c:\...\main.cpp(68): error C2664: 'void fizzbuzz::<lambda_9027e592dd51e6f4c5342b61ff8c23f0>::operator ()(std::function<std::string (std::string)>) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'void' to 'std::function<std::string (std::string)>'
1>c:\...\main.cpp(68): note: Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types
1>Done building project "Data Structure Samples.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I check this against CompilerExplorer found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8v4z68), This code compiles with all three of the major compilers: GCC, Clang, and MSVC...

I know that C++17 supports both `lambdas` and `std::function<T>`, but is this type of implementation or usage specific to a newer version of the compiler? Meaning is this technique or usage only available with say C++20 and later? If so, what can be done to this code snippet so that it can be compiled under Visual Studio 2017 using C++17 that will provide the same semantics and behavior?

---

**Edit**

Here are all of my Compiler's Command-Line Settings in regards to the C/C++ Language section:

`/JMC /permissive- /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /Qspectre /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /std:c++latest /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\Data Structure Samples.pch" /diagnostics:classic`

Comment: I'm not asking about the compiler errors, they are fairly straightforward, my current compiler and settings are complaining that the arguments are ambiguous. I'm just looking for a work around!

Comment: FYI: I have my compiler language flag set to: `ISO C++ Latest Draft Standard (/std:c++latest)`. It also appears that auto type deduction is not working within the context of these lambdas or the way they are being implemented...

Comment: From the settings you have described, I see no reason why this should be failing. It seems to be having an issue deducing the return type from the ternary expressions, since one branch returns `std::function` and the other returns a lambda. What version is your Visual Studio up to? Compiler-Explorer only supports the oldest of "2017 Update 9", so I'm wondering if you're on an archaic version that had a deduction bug

Comment: @Human-Compiler When I bring up Visual Studio's help dialog box, it shows that my version is `15.9.24`. I haven't gotten around to it yet, but when I redo my entire PC meaning reinstalling Windows in which I'm still using Windows 7 x64... I will eventually install a new and clean version of Visual Studio 2019 to have access to C++20... until then, I'm just sticking with my current compiler... I could use a VM to set up Linux Environment and install GCC but that's more work than what I feel like doing at this moment and I'm not real savy with Linux atm... Hope this helps!

Comment: @Human-Compiler yeah, it's got me stumped... I thought it would compile, and it should for AFAIK Visual Studio 2017 running in C++17 should fully support both `Lambdas` and `std::function<T>`... Not sure why it's generating ambiguous code with the auto type deduction...

Comment: `15.9.24` I would think should be recent enough to support this... The oldest MSVC version on Compiler Explorer is `v19.14` which I believe should correspond to Visual Studios version `15.7.5`, and it accepts this code. Unfortunately I'm not sure why this isn't working. The only guess I would have is that something isn't set up correctly for the current language version (which you have stated should be set to `/std:c++latest`). Hopefully someone else may be able to catch what I'm not seeing

Comment: @Human-Compiler even if I add this to the end of both lambdas: `-> std::function<std::string(std::string)>` it still produces the same ambiguous errors...

Comment: I may have found a similar problem in an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41637152/1678770). It seems that Visual Studios 2017 RC at the time was not correctly determining the resulting expression of ternary statements. I'm guessing that this is a problem in the MSVC version. Unfortunately MSVC is notorious for not bothering to implement C++ correctly to spec

Comment: @Human-Compiler Seems to make sense, leave it to Mircosoft to distribute broken code upon release allowing the consumer market to be the guinea pigs and testers... Also, here is a full list of my C/C++ command line settings: `/JMC /permissive- /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /Qspectre /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /std:c++latest /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\Data Structure Samples.pch" /diagnostics:classic `

Comment: Add those flags to the question -- that just helped to diagnose the problem

Comment: @Human-Compiler I may have to open a new question that is specific to these generated compiler errors within Visual Studio in regards to the Ternary Operator and the ambiguity it is causing, just to check and see if it is a known compiler bug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug; `a?b:c` is legal if `b` can be converted to an rvalue of type `c` and not vice versa (among other rules).

To fix:

```
auto fizz = [=](std::function<std::string(std::string)> f) {
    if(n%3 == 0)
      f = [=](auto) { return "Fizz" + f(""); };
    return f;
};
auto buzz = [=](std::function<std::string(std::string)> f) {
    if(n % 5 == 0)
      f = [=](auto) { return "Buzz" + f(""); };
    return f;
};
```

that should work.

Comment: I'll have to check that out!

Comment: This implementation worked!!! Therefore the ambiguity that MSVC 2017 is generating as a compiler error is in fact a BUG within the Compiler itself!!!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that MSVC has an issue with handling the deduction of ternary statements when in the presence of the `/permissive-` flag. The `/permissive-` flag *should* be forcing MSVC to compile with [strict standards conformance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-160), however ironically this appears to be breaking what [should be valid code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637450/1678770).

This can be reproduced on Compiler Explorer easily: <kbd>[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/cEK41d)</kbd>. This appears to be fixed in newer MSVC versions with v19.25 onward <kbd>[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/dPjsPW)</kbd>

---

Unfortunately there are few ways to fix this since it's a compiler bug.
You're limited to:

- Updating your compiler,
- Removing `/permissive-`, or
- Not using ternary statements that return different types (e.g. use `if`/`else` with different returns instead)

Comment: This allowed the code to compile, build and run by changing the `/permissive-` flag, however, the output I'm getting when running it through my `for loop` prints `FizzBuzz` on every line of output... That's why I gave you an upvote but didn't accept this as a solution to my problem.

Comment: @FrancisCugler The code should generate [correct output](https://godbolt.org/z/34M1Eq). Since MSVC seems to be borked with the diagnostics coming from `/permissive-`, I'm guessing that what the code generated must also be borked as well. Either way, that would be the subject for a different SO question at that point. All I can suggest is to avoid this pattern until you can upgrade the compiler

Comment: The idea of using the `ternary` statements is to reduce the amount of  `conditional checks` on each iteration of the code in which Kevlin explains in his video..., removing the `/permissive-` flag works in compilation but produces invalid output, and updating my compiler, well I already stated that situation in a previous comment... but I do appreciate your time and effort in helping me to track and narrow down this bug!

Comment: Eventually, when I get around to backing up my data, wiping my drives, and installing a fully clean OS, I will then install at minimal Visual Studio 2019... I might even look into having a version of GCC or Clang to be installed...